# Read and Write into Cells with php spreadsheet cause performance issue

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am using phpSpreadsheet to read my 'A' column and check if this ID is in my database valid and saved it with some new information into a new Excel file . With few datasets it is quite fast,  but when it comes more than 100 Ids it becomes really slow. Does anyone know a better approach?

```
    public static function export($date, $file)
    {

        //read from spreadsheet
        $loadFile = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($file);
        $worksheet = $loadFile->getSheet(0);
        

        //get ID Rows
        $first_row= $worksheet->rangeToArray('A1:A'.$loadFile->getSheet(0)->getHighestDataRow());

        //create new spreadsheet
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $sheet->fromArray($first_row);
        $result= array();

        //problem is here
        foreach($first_row as $value)
        {
            foreach($value as $ID)
            {
                //check FOREACH ID in database if this id is valid, which will be really slow after some times;
                $getCarFromDatabase = CarService::getCar($ID);

                array_push($result,getCarFromDatabase);
                ...
            }
        }
       
        $id_size = sizeof($first_row );

        $sheet->setCellValue('C1', "Car");

        //then write the result into in the new excel file
        for($row = 2; $row <= $id_size ; $row++) {
            $sheet->setCellValue('C' .$row, $result[$row-2]);
        }
        //create excel file
        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
        $filename = "filename.xlsx";
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
        return $writer->save("php://output");

    }
```

Is there a better way approach, to speed up the things up? Thank you in Advance!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is using CSV an option (if it's about Excel-compatibility)?

Comment: unfortunately not, I am only allowed to use phpspreadsheet...

Comment: Syntax error `foreach($value as $ ID)`

Comment: So what exactly is the performance issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly for example I have to check 100 Ids with database, so with double loops is quite slow to get the excel file from backend to frontend

Comment: Please, copy and paste the real code, this has little typo's in it that I assume are not in the read code, next one is `array_push($result,getCarFromDatabase);`

Comment: My suggestion: (1) just look at column A and increment the row (starting from row 2) by one each time (so get the value of A2, then A3, then A4...) until the value of it becomes blank then stop. (2) For each value of the Ax, query your db and get the Name and Car data , put them into cell of column B and C respectively . (3) If ID is **not** indexed, then create an index on the ID field. Reason: Such linear approach in a single looping querying the db on an indexed field should not have much performance problem.